# Passage in a proof, with construction resembling the Rees algebra

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

I am reading http://www.math.cornell.edu/~irena/papers/regularity.pdf

Let $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be standard graded and let $I\subset S$ be an ideal minimally generated by homogeneous polynomials $f_1,\dots,f_m$ with $m\ge2$.
In the paper the authors introduce the ring $T=S[y_1,\dots,y_m,z]$  and they study the map in page 11
$$\varphi : T \longrightarrow S[It,t^2]\subset S[t],\qquad y_i\longmapsto f_it,\qquad z\longmapsto t^2.
$$

In page 12, Proposition 3.2, they prove that $\ker(\varphi)$ is generated by
$$y_iy_j-zf_if_j,\qquad 1\le i,j\le m$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^m c_{ij}y_j,\qquad 1\le j\le \mathrm{rank}(F_0),$$
where the second set of elements corresponds to the syzygies of $I$, following Assumptions and Notation 2.2 in page 9.

I am trying to replace $t^2$ with $t^2+at+b$, for some $a,b\in S$. That is, I am considering the map
$$\psi : T \longrightarrow S[t],\qquad y_i\longmapsto f_it,\qquad z\longmapsto t^2+at+b.$$
In order to make the map homogeneous, I assume that $a$ and $b$ are homogeneous and
$$\deg(a)=1,\qquad\deg(b)=2.$$

I have been doing some experiments with a computer algebra system, and it seems that $\ker(\psi)$ is generated by the elements
$$\sum_{i=1}^m c_{ij}y_j,\qquad 1\le j\le \mathrm{rank}(F_0),$$
and
$$y_iy_j-zf_if_j+bf_if_j+af_iy_j,\qquad 1\le i,j\le m.$$
I can repeat almost everything of the proof in the paper in this case with $t^2+at+b$, apart from one passage. 
I want to prove that $\ker(\psi)$ is contained in the ideal generated by the elements above. Let $e\in\ker(\psi)$ and write $e=f+g$, where $f\in(y_1,\dots,y_m)^2$ and $g\in S[z]\mathrm{Span}_k\{1,y_1,\dots,y_m\}$. I understand that, as in the proof of the article, it is enough to prove the inclusion in the case with $f=0$, so write
$$e=h(z)+\sum_{i=1}^mh_i(z)y_i,$$
with $h,h_1,\dots,h_m\in S[z]$. Then
$$0=\psi(e)=h(t^2+at+b)+\sum_{i=1}^mh_i(t^2+at+b)tf_i\in S[t],$$
while in the article we have
$$0=\varphi(e)=h(t^2)+\sum_{i=1}^mh_i(t^2)tf_i.$$
At this point in the article they deduce that $h(t^2)=0$, because it contains only even powers of $t$, while the sum contains only odd powers of $t$, and hence $h(z)=0$. But in my case this does not work anymore.

I would like to deduce that $h(z)=0$, because after that the proof would go on just like the one in the paper. But so far I didn't manage to do that.

This is what I found so far. If we write $h(z)=c_0+c_1z+\dots+c_dz^d$, for some $c_i\in S$, then I think that we have
$$c_0+c_1b+c_2b^2+\dots+c_db^d=0,$$
because this is the coefficient of degree zero in $\psi(e)$ and the sum in $\psi(e)$ has no term of degree zero. The other thing I think is that if $$j>\mathrm{max}\{\deg(h_i)\mid i=1,\dots,m\},$$
then $c_j=0$, where the degrees of the $h_i$'s are taken with respect to $z$.

I thought that maybe I could try to prove that $h=0$ by induction on $\deg(h)$, but it doesn't sound very convincing: how could I say "let $d=\deg(h)>0$, we find a polynomial to which we can apply the inductive hypothesis and then it comes out $h=0$"? I think, if it can be made, that it can be made directly.

EDIT: Maybe I have an idea. I write every $c_i$ as a sum of homogeneous components as
$$c_i= g_0^{(i)}+\dots+g_{d_i}^{(i)},$$
where $d_i=\deg(c_i)$ and each $g_j^{(i)}$ is homogeneous of degree $j$. Now, since $\deg(b)=2$, the homogeneous component of degree $0$ in $c_0+c_1b+\dots+c_db^d$ is
$$g_0^{(0)}=0,$$
because I already know $c_0+c_1b+\dots+c_db^d=0$. The homogeneous component of degree $1$ is
$$g_1^{(0)}=0.$$
Now there is a problem: the other homogeneous components go on like this:
$$\begin{cases}
g^{(0)}_2+g^{(1)}_0b=0\\
g^{(0)}_3+g_1^{(1)}b=0\\
g^{(0)}_4+g^{(1)}_2b+g^{(2)}_0b^2=0\\
\vdots
\end{cases}$$
and it doesn't look like I can use the first rows to cancel some terms in the others... Is it a good idea though?

EDIT 2:
I wrote explicitly all the "pieces" of the form $(t^2+at+b)^n$ in $\psi(e)$, they are
\begin{eqnarray}
(t^2+at+b)^n & = & \sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni (t^2+at)^ib^{n-i}\\
& = & \sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni  b^{n-i}t^i \sum_{k=0}^i\binom ik t^k a^{i-k}\\
& = & \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^i\binom ni \binom ik b^{n-i}a^{i-k} t^{i+k}
\end{eqnarray}
by the binomial formula. Now, I have tried to write this down for every polynomial $h,h_1,\dots,h_m$ and find some relationships between them, but it seems like an endless hopeless calculation. Do you think this could be helpful?

Can someone please help? Thank you very much in advance!